# RavenDB index to get max value of a document property not working?

Tags: .net, indexing, ravendb

I've created the below index to try to get the next ItemNumber.  ItemNumber is not a raven identifier, so it is assigned by the application.  What the index is supposed to do is return 0 if there aren't any Items in the database. Otherwise it should return Max + 1.  It almost works, but with one glaring problem.  Instead of returning max + 1, it returns max + 2.  The end result of that is that the ItemNumbers skip every other number.  If I remove the '+ 1', it behaves like it is supposed to and returns the existing max but that's not what I need.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
public class NextItemNumber : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Item, NextItemNumber.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public long ItemNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public NextItemNumber()
    {
        Map = items => from item in items
                          select new
                          {
                              // item.ItemNumber is a string
                              ItemNumber = Convert.ToInt64(item.ItemNumber)
                          };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by 0 into g
                            select new
                            {
                                ItemNumber = g.Max(x => x.ItemNumber) + 1
                            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the reduce, you want something like this:

```
                            ItemNumber = g.Max(x=>x.ItemNumber )
```

Comment: Thanks, Ayende. I cleaned up my code per your suggestion (changes are reflected above). I'm seeing the same result. Say the existing max in the db is 10, the index is returning 12.  This is just on local so I'm going to update my build. It's currently 2261.

Comment: I updated to build 2375 and this index is still returning max + 2 instead of Max + 1. May be a bug?